# Finding the average of n numbers with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that finds the average of n numbers inputted but I'm having trouble getting the recursions to work. The program sort of works but it doesn't exit out of the while statement when I want it to.

```
print("This program 'is' designed to find the average of n numbers you input\n") #print statement that introduces the average finder

counter = 0 #this counter will count how many numbers the user has inserted into the     program and will be used as denominator 
sum_of_numbers = 0 #this number is set as 0 as currently the sum is 0, as more numbers are inputed, they will be added together

first_question = input('''Would you like to enter a number? Type "yes" if you do, and "no" if you don't. \n\n''') #takes input of yes or no to see whether user wants to find average of numbers

while first_question == "yes" :
    ent_num = int(input("Enter your number here:"))
    sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + ent_num
    counter = counter + 1
    second_question = input('''Would you like to enter another number after this? Type "yes" if you do, and "no" if you don't. \n''')
     while second_question == "yes" :
         ent_num = int(input("Enter your next number here: "))
         sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + ent_num
        counter = counter + 1
    else :
    print("Your average is " + str(sum_of_numbers/counter))
```

Can someone please help me figure it out?

I can't use functions such as try or eval or len its all really basic stuff like the 3rd day in my class

Comment: is there any reason you're triple quoting your prompts?

Comment: @Ryan Haining, have you tried it without triple quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one loop to work.  Just ask you question, get the input, and loop.  When you enter no, then the loop will exit and compute your average.

```
print("This program 'is' designed to find the average of n numbers you input\n") #print statement that introduces the average finder

counter = 0 #this counter will count how many numbers the user has inserted into the     program and will be used as denominator 
sum_of_numbers = 0 #this number is set as 0 as currently the sum is 0, as more numbers are inputed, they will be added together

first_question = input('''Would you like to enter a number? Type "yes" if you do, and "no" if you don't. \n\n''') #takes input of yes or no to see whether user wants to find average of numbers

while first_question == "yes" :
    ent_num = int(input("Enter your number here:"))
    sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + ent_num
    counter = counter + 1
    first_question = input('''Would you like to enter another number after this? Type "yes" if you do, and "no" if you don't. \n''')

print("Your average is " + str(sum_of_numbers/counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

first_question is never changed and also you should do the math after you break out of the second while indicating you are done.  The first_question always stays "yes" since you assign the output to second_question.  Since you're never going to ask the first_question agaain simply:

```
print("This program 'is' designed to find the average of n numbers you input\n") #print statement that introduces the average finder

counter = 0 #this counter will count how many numbers the user has inserted into the     program and will be used as denominator 
sum_of_numbers = 0 #this number is set as 0 as currently the sum is 0, as more numbers are inputed, they will be added together

first_question = input('''Would you like to enter a number? Type "yes" if you do, and "no" if you don't. \n\n''')

 #takes input of yes or no to see whether user wants to find average of numbers.

if first_question == "yes" :
    ent_num = int(input("Enter your number here:"))
    sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + ent_num
    counter = counter + 1
    second_question = input('''Would you like to enter another number after this? Type "yes" if you do, and "no" if you don't. \n''')
    while second_question == "yes" :
         ent_num = int(input("Enter your next number here: "))
         sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + ent_num
         counter = counter + 1
    print("Your average is " + str(sum_of_numbers/counter))
else :
    print("Well if you're just going to answer no off the bat why did you bother running me\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is concise enough not to comment it. It's python after all !

Here is a short working version:

```
print("This program 'is' designed to find the average of n numbers you input\n")

first_question = 'Would you like to enter a number? (type "yes" if you do)\n\n'
second_question = 'Would you like to enter another number after this? (type "yes" if you do)\n'

sum_of_numbers = 0
counter = 0
if input(first_question) == "yes" :
    sum_of_numbers += int(input("Enter your number here:"))
    counter += 1
    while input(second_question) == "yes" :
        sum_of_numbers += int(input("Enter your next number here: "))
        counter += 1
    print("Your average is " + str(sum_of_numbers/counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly cleaner version that shows some new ideas and gives a more accurate result.

```
print("This program 'is' designed to find the average of n numbers you input\n")
counter = 0
sum_of_numbers = 0
q = '''Would you like to enter %s? Type "yes" if you do, and "no" if you don't. \n'''
qn = 'a number'
while input(q % qn) == "yes" :
    sum_of_numbers += input("Enter your number here:")
    counter += 1
    qn = 'another number after this'

print("Your average is " + str(1.*sum_of_numbers/counter))
```